# Source model "marketplace/entity_attribute_source_table" not found for attribute "customerstatus"

Tags: magento-1.9, error

When I go to Manage Customers and click on any of the customers, I get "There has been an error processing your request" and the following error in the log:

> Source model "marketplace/entity_attribute_source_table" not found for attribute "customerstatus"

and then a long list of codes.
What is creating the issue?

Comment: Seems you are using marketplace extension. Install the same extension in localhost or in demo site, then export the database table missing and import to the site where you are getting error. don't forget to take the backup before importing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a custom customer attribute from your marketplace module, for which the options were coming from the module itself. Now, it looks like either you have disabled the module or uninstalled it. So now, your attribute is left without the source of it's options. You  can either re-install the module or you can delete that attribute from the customer entity.

Comment: yes, I have unistalled the marketplace module, now how to delete that attribute from the customer entity?

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141874/delete-custom-customer-attribute-in-magento